# Use of te-form before なる

Tags: grammar, て-form

> 今こそマルフォイを一対一でやっつけるまたとないチャンスだ。**逃してなる**ものか。
> This was a unique chance to beat Malfoy one-on-one. How could he miss it.

I don't understand the purpose of なる in 逃してなるものか. How is it different from 逃すものか?
I haven't seen なる preceded by a て-form before.